# Insert document in Collection using ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am having an issue within stupid-simple piece of ruby/mongo code below:

```
def initMongo
  @client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'])
end

def creatDB(name)
  @database = @database.new(@client, name)
end

def creatCollection(name)
  @collection = @collection.new(@database, name)
  @collection.insert_one({name: 'test'})
  @collection.inspect
end
```

With `@collection.insert_one({name: 'test'})` I get :

> /collection.rb:129:in write_concern': undefined method write_concern' for Mongo::Client:Class

Ruby v2.2.3 Mongo v2.2

Comment: What ruby adapter to mongo do you use? `mongo`?

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes, I have include `Mongo` and `require 'mongo'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here :

```
def initMongo
  @client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'])
end
```

Replace by :

```
def initMongo
  @client = @client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'])
end
```